# In my profile page, can I revert back to the screen before I selected Track My Next Privilege?

Tags: support, profile-page, privileges

My profile page informed me I had earned a privilege, and displayed a message offering to track the next one. I clicked on that, thinking the privilege list would appear, at which point I could decide if I wanted to leave the screen alone, or choose to make my progress toward the next one public.

What happened instead was that the system automatically switched to the next privilege. I was hoping I could just "undo" the choice I had made, leaving the screen as it was before I selected "Track the next one."

The concept resembles other features, like voting, which give a certain period of time before a choice becomes permanent.

Comment: If you just earned it, what's to track? It is already earned, no? Just trying to understand.

Comment: @Oded Yes, but what I wanted was to leave things alone, as in not publicly tracking the next one at all.

Comment: We don't really have a concept of tracking privileges that have already been earned, given that one is tracking progress towards earning them. It is kinda weird to track progress towards something already completed.

Comment: @Oded I see what you're saying. Perhaps I wasn't clear in that I thought that the "track the next one" option would lead me to the list, and then I could decide whether or not I wanted to show the next one. It's probably pride or something, but I don't necessarily want that next one shown until I get closer to it. :)

Comment: @Sue While it is public, remember it is on the non-default page...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my profile page, can I revert back to the screen before I selected
>   Track My Next Privilege?

I understand what you want, but the new profile tracking functions are specifically for "tracking" things, and you cannot track an already earned privilege.

As you stated, there are already multiple other methods to see your current privilege status.

Even though the function does show the currently earned one, I don't think it's designed to do this *specifically* as an option to show your current level. More to show the one you've just earned because it's the *natural* thing to do before you choose which one to track.

> It's probably pride or something

I really wouldn't worry about that. Anyone who in anyway sees anything negative from your current rep/privilege level simply does not warrant/deserve your concerns.
Decent people do not view or judge you based on your rep level.

Besides, people will know what your current privileges are without even going to your profile - from the rep you have shown all over the site in your question/answers/etc.

> The concept resembles other features, like voting, which give a
>   certain period of time before a choice becomes permanent.

True, but voting is *substantially*  more important, given that voting affects other users rep, their answers being moved up, or down or even hidden, etc.

I'm not against what you want whatsoever, and is *technically* possible, but it is dev time, and for that it really needs to be worthwhile - how many users would use it, how useful it is, etc.
The grace on voting is quite important to have, whereas your request is a little more "personal" and not essential in any way.

### Alternative Option

Rather than "undo" the action, you could raise a new feature-request asking to be able to permanently choose to show *either* "track next" or "show current".
This will likely be seen/used by more users, and is a bit simpler than an "undo" function. It's just a clear option which is always there.

Although, I'm not sure if this or an undo option would be implemented as the function is for "tracking next" not "showing current".

Worth a try, though :)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a thoughtful response. I was hoping the feature was there, but I won't waste anyone's time requesting it. Would it make sense to request a link from the word Privilege in that spot to the list of privileges, which is what I thought would happen? I'll defer to your advice.

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, that wouldn't resolve your issue raised in your question. And changes nothing for a "tracking" function, as it would just introduce a new way to see your privileges, and we already have plenty of those IMO. As for my advice, it's not necessarily the same as other user's opinions, so don't *not* ask or request something based solely on what I've wrote :)